# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined EncodeStream.js

Tags: angular, npm, angular8

I am using pdf-kit to generate Web to PDF. For this i installed these package via npm in angular(last version) that uses some libs like "fs,stream,zlib,.."

For this when i run ng serve it showed many errors like:

```
Can't resolve 'fs' in '\node_modules\..'
Can't resolve 'stream' in '\node_modules\..'
```

To bypass this i added specific entries in package.json. Now the **ng serve** is running fine but getting runtime error on browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at __extends (EncodeStream.js:5)
    at EncodeStream.js:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (EncodeStream.js:147)
    at Object../node_modules/restructure/src/EncodeStream.js (EncodeStream.js:151)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:5)
    at Object../node_modules/restructure/index.js (index.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/fontkit/index.js (index.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

component.ts file :

```
import * as pdfkit from 'pdfkit';
import * as blobstream from 'blob-stream';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  //Some code..

  downloadPDF(){
    var doc=new pdfkit();
    var stream= doc.pipe(blobstream());
    doc.fontSize(25).text('Test PDF !',100,100);
    doc.circle(280,200,50).fill("#6600FF");
    doc.end();
    stream.on('finish', function(){
      window.open(stream.toBlobURL('application/pdf'));
    });
  }

}
```

Any help much appreciated..

Comment: can you show the code where are u getting this problem?

Comment: @ngShravil.py Added Code.